# Using which() to find values between certain posix times and fill NA when there is no data

Tags: r, posixct

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame("posix_time" = as.POSIXct(c("2021-07-01 01:00:00 CEST", "2021-07-01 01:10:00 CEST", "2021-07-01 01:20:00 CEST", 
                                   "2021-07-01 01:30:00 CEST", "2021-07-01 01:40:00 CEST", "2021-07-01 01:50:00 CEST",
                                   "2021-07-01 02:00:00 CEST", "2021-07-01 02:10:00 CEST", "2021-07-01 02:20:00 CEST")),
                  "value" = c(5, 8, 15, 7, 12, 5, 89, 1, 17))
```

Now I want to get the index or in this case data of "value" directly using the which-function. Doing it like this works fine:

```
temp <- dat$value[which(dat$posix_time >= "2021-07-01 01:00:00" & dat$posix_time <= "2021-07-01 02:00:00")]
```

This should then be written into a pre defined matrix of a certain size:

```
mat <- matrix(NA, ncol = 15, nrow = 1)
```

Where ncol is a number of timesteps. Here it would be:

```
colnames(mat) <- c("00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", "01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20")
```

Now I would like to write the value into the matrix that corresponds to the correct time from `dat`. But I am not sure how to do that.

It should look like this:

```
00:00 00:10 00:20 00:30 00:40 00:50 01:00 01:10 01:20 01:30 01:40 01:50 02:00 02:10 02:20
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     5     8    15     7    12     5    89    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dat <- dat[which(dat$posix_time >= "2021-07-01 01:00:00" & dat$posix_time <= "2021-07-01 02:00:00"), ]
mat[match(gsub("^.* (\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*$", "\\1", dat$posix_time), colnames(mat))] <- dat$value

#     00:00 00:10 00:20 00:30 00:40 00:50 01:00 01:10 01:20 01:30 01:40 01:50 02:00 02:10 02:20
#[1,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     5     8    15     7    12     5    89    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. But it also gives the values for ```02:10``` and ```02:20``` when it should have ended at ```02:00```. As I don't fully understand what the gsub part does I can't figure out why it gives the last two values as well eventhough the which() command does not

Comment: Right, because `which` explicitly does it, but not my command. You could subset first (see edit)

Comment: You can also use `format(dat$posix_time, '%H:%M')` instead of `gsub("^.* (\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*$", "\\1", dat$posix_time)`. It's simpler to understand

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, subset `dat` within a certain time range.

```r
dat2 <- dat[dat$posix_time >= "2021-07-01 01:00:00" & dat$posix_time <= "2021-07-01 02:00:00", ]
```

Then you can use column names of `mat` as indices.

```r
mat[, strftime(dat2$posix_time, "%H:%M")] <- dat2$value
mat

#      00:00 00:10 00:20 00:30 00:40 00:50 01:00 01:10 01:20 01:30 01:40 01:50 02:00 02:10 02:20
# [1,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     5     8    15     7    12     5    89    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `format` to get the date at the format we want and then match, i.e.

```
dat$value[match(colnames(mat), format(dat$posix_time, '%H:%M'))]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA  5  8 15  7 12  5 89  1 17
```